# Where can I find statistics on the average number of papers published while working on a PhD?

Tags: phd, publications

I'm interested in this, because I want to know if there is something like an average number that we might find.

I am looking for statistics on the number of papers published while working on a PhD, preferably by general field of study (e.g. Physics, History, etc., not "Quantum Electrodynamics") and the country where the PhD was completed. If possible, the duration of PhD and amount of course work should also be parameters.

Comment: Note that this is a question about where to find statistics, and *not* an invitation to share how many publications during the PhD is normal in one's field.

Comment: To clarify do you want publications that are directly arise from the PhD or publications that are published while an author is a PhD student.

Comment: Any such numbers are meaningless because of huge cultural differences even within a single subject. A PhD in the UK takes 3-4 years, whereas twice that length is common in the US. Also, it seems likely that there are significant variations in publication rates by subfield: maybe quantum electrodynamicists publish more papers than astrophysicists, but you want to lump them all together.

Answer (score 5):

[Byrnes (2007)](http://pss.sagepub.com/content/18/4/283) found that for tenured faculty in top departments of psychology in the US there was a correlation between the publication rate during the first 7 years following a PhD and the number of publications during the PhD.

> individuals in the bottom quartile published an average of 1.03 predoctoral articles, those in the middle 50% and top 25% published 2.00 and 3.03 predoctoral articles, respectively

Note that the quartiles refer tot he number of articles published during the 7 years following the awarding of the PhD and not the number of predoctoral articles.

This study obviously includes only a small subset of all Psychologists (those who have gotten tenure at top Psychology departments), but may provide a hook into relevant literature.

Comment: Also see this recently accepted paper in BioScience (Not yet accessible) for a similar approach, looking at scientific "success" as predicted by early papers, original language and university rank: [Predicting publication success for biologists](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.1525/bio.2013.63.10.9?uid=371589391&uid=3738744&uid=2&uid=3&uid=37840&uid=5909240&uid=67&uid=62&sid=21102656903717). Summary here: [Early to press is best for success](http://conservationbytes.com/2013/09/19/early-to-press-is-best-for-success/).